# Need help for finding every row/column css property from grid-template-columns css string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I am building an app where I need a row and column CSS parser. For that reason, I need to extract CSS data using regex and return an array.

Css string is:
`1fr minmax(75px, auto) fit-content(40%) repeat(3, 200px) 200px repeat(auto-fill, 100px) 300px repeat(auto-fill, minmax(75px, auto))`

Array output need:
`["1fr", "minmax(75px, auto)", "fit-content(40%)", "repeat(3, 200px)", "200px", "repeat(auto-fill, 100px)", "300px", "repeat(auto-fill, minmax(75px, auto))"]`

I tried:

```
const getTotalColumnOrRowArray = (css_string) => {
    // abc123 ||OR|| abc-abc(abc123, abc123) ||OR|| abc
    let arr = css_string.match(/\d+[a-zA-Z\S]+|([a-zA-Z-\S]+\([a-zA-Z-\d\S]+, [a-zA-Z-\d\S]+\))|[a-zA-Z\S]+/g);
    return arr;
};
```

But it can't return `"repeat(auto-fill, minmax(75px, auto))"` this value.

Comment: If the nesting of the parenthesis is only 1 level `[^\s()]+(?:\([^\s()]+(?:\([^()]+\))?(?:, *[^\s()]+(?:\([^()]+\))?)*\))?` See https://regex101.com/r/Ny9x75/1

Comment: Thanks, @Thefourthbird. It solves my problem.

Comment: @JakirHossen kindly mark the answer accepted if it solves you problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is always a part without parenthesis to match first, followed by an optional part with parenthesis which by it self only can have one layer of nesting:

```
[^\s()]+(?:\([^\s()]+(?:\([^()]+\))?(?:, *[^\s()]+(?:\([^()]+\))?)*\))?
```

In parts

- `[^\s()]+` Match 1+ times any char except `(` `)` or a whitespace char
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\(` Match `(`
  - `[^\s()]+` Match 1+ times any char except `(` `)` or a whitespace char
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\([^()]+\)` Match `(` 1+ times any char except `(` `)` or a whitespace char and match `)`
  - `)?` Close the group and make it optional
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `, *[^\s()]+` Match comma, optional spaces and 1+ times any char except `(` `)` or a whitespace char
    - `(?:\([^()]+\))?` Match an optional part with parenthesis as before
  - `)*` Close the group and optionally repeat
  - `\)` Match `)`
- `)?` Close the group and make it optional

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ny9x75/1)

```js
const s = "1fr minmax(75px, auto) fit-content(40%) repeat(3, 200px) 200px repeat(auto-fill, 100px) 300px repeat(auto-fill, minmax(75px, auto))";
const regex = /[^\s()]+(?:\([^\s()]+(?:\([^()]+\))?(?:, *[^\s()]+(?:\([^()]+\))?)*\))?/g;
let result = Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[0])
console.log(result);
```